# Run a series of commands at a specific time (sleep or at or other) in KSH

Tags: date, unix, sleep, ksh, at-job

So here's my problem: using KSH I need to run a script that takes a time input that could range in its style (now + 5 minutes, 23:00, Tuesday, etc) and at the time runs a loop that checks for a condition every 10 seconds until the condition is met. My dilemma is that the date program doesn't support the -d option for me to just be able to sleep until that specified time. I'm thinking that I would have to use the at command but I'm not having any luck. Basic syntax is:

```
at $time 
  while sleep 10 ; do
    if [ x ] ; then
      echo "Done"
      break
    fi
  done
```

I'm open to using things other than 'at' but the only other thing I've found that I think could work is to calculate the time in seconds to sleep by using date -d which I already said won't work...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
#!/bin/ksh
at $@ <<%
    exec > $(tty) 2>&1
    while [ ! x ] ; do sleep 10 ; done
    echo Done
%
```